# Change image path src to data-src on Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, drupal-7, lazy-loading

I want to use [LazyLoad](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) plugin. Searched modules about this jQuery plugin but don't work for me. Moreover, will use many options.

So, first rule:

> Latest version of Lazy Load is not a drop in replacement to your
>   webpage. New browsers load image even if you remove the src attribute
>   with JavaScript. Now you must alter your html code. Put placeholder
>   image into src attribute of your img tag. Real image url should be
>   stored data-original attribute.  Good thing is you can now
>   put all your JavaScript to the end of the page. If you want to support
>   non JavaScript browsers there is an extra step. You must include
>   original image inside  tag. Read the documentation below.

---

But i don't know how can i do this? Is it possible Javascript? Or another soluitons?

Answer (score 0):

Most images go through [`theme_image()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7), which you can override in your theme's template.php file like so:

```
function MYTHEME_image($vars) {
  $attributes = $variables['attributes'];
  $attributes['data-src'] = file_create_url($variables['path']); // <-- Change is here

  foreach (array('width', 'height', 'alt', 'title') as $key) {
    if (isset($variables[$key])) {
      $attributes[$key] = $variables[$key];
    }
  }

  return '<img' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . ' />';
}
```